# Add new row only if text column is not number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've started to learn sql, now I'm writing project in `Postgresql`. For example I've got table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
  id_employee serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying,
  surname character varying,
  salary numeric,
  position character varying,
  login character varying,
  password character varying,
  CONSTRAINT employee_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_employee )
)
```

I want to allow inserting new rows only if column name and surname don't include numbers.
Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: In aplication it will be easy, but I must do this in database

Comment: BTW, thanks for showing your schema. In future, please always mention your database version, and where there's an error, the exact command text and error text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, before messing with names, please read [this article about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).  Please do not add constraints to names. Ideally do not even split "surname" and "first name".

If you must do this you will probably want a regular expression based constraint.

```
CONSTRAINT name_no_numeric_chars
  CHECK (name !~ '[[:digit:]]');
```

Comment: @user3187296 Great. Now please don't use it.